# Is this way of generating a securerandom biginteger secure?

Tags: java, security, random, biginteger

So I tried this line of code in java which generates a random integer that is 40 bytes long. I have no clue if it's secure and I wondered if anyone with a little bit more experience than me could explain.

I would like to know if this is cryptographically secure. meaning is this a secure way of generating a random number that's a BigInteger. If it isn't secure what would be a good way to generate a full cryptographically random BigInteger.

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
BigInteger key_limit = new BigInteger("10000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
int key_length = key_limit.bitLength();
BigInteger key_1 = new BigInteger(key_length, random);
```

Comment: Just do `new BigInteger(8 * 40, random)`, and since you're using `SecureRandom`, why wouldn't it be cryptographically secure?

Comment: @Andreas I was just wondering if it was secure because of my approach xD. so i had no clue if it was a good idea

Answer (score 1):

You will get a `BigInteger` containing a securely generated random number that way.

However, that method for calculating the bit length is (to say the least) odd.  I don't know about you, but most programmers would find it difficult to work out how many zeros there are in that string.  Then, the computation is going to give you a bit count such that 2<sup>bits</sup> is less than the number.

It would make a lot more sense (to me) to just specify a bit count directly and code it, and add a comment to explain it.

To a first approximation<sup>1</sup> 2<sup>(10*N)</sup> is 1000<sup>N</sup>.  However, the former is slightly greater than the latter.  That means if your code is *intended* to give you 40 byte random keys, your computed key length will be off by one.

---

<sup>1 - Experienced programmers remember that ... and inexperienced programmers can use a programmer's calculator.</sup>

Comment: That big number is exactly 40 digits long. OP thinks this is what '40 bytes of key data' means. OP has a pesky musk rat infestation in their wood and bamboo house and is asking you for a bazooka. I have no idea what SO policy is on such questions, but morally/eductionally speaking, 'hand it to them, without indicating that this might possible not be the best plan' can't possibly be the right move.

Comment: You are drawing conclusions about what the OP is doing that are not actually justified.  This question just asks if the number is generated securely.  It says nothing (nadda) about what the number will be used for.

Comment: And you miss my point about the big decimal number string.  How does a normal programmer count the zeros?  The fact that the OP has told us what the code is trying to do doesn't help the poor sod of a programmer who has to read the code in 6 months time.

Comment: _You are drawing conclusions about what the OP is doing that are not actually justified_ - it's obvious, bordering on the self-evident.

Answer (score 1):

You're rolling your own crypto.

Be prepared to fail. The odds that the code you end up writing will actually be secure are infinitesemal. It is very, very, **very** easy to make a mistake. These mistakes are almost always extremely hard to test for (for example, your algorithm may leak information based on how long it takes to process different input, thus letting an attacker figure out the key in a matter of hours. Did you plan on writing a test that checks if all attempts to decode anything, be it the actual ciphertext, mangled ciphertext, half of ciphertext, crafted input specifically designed to try to derive key info by checking how long it takes to process, and random gobbledygook all take exactly equally long? Do you know what kind of crafted inputs you need to test for, even?)

On the topic of timing attacks, specifically, once you write `BigInteger`, you've almost certainly lost the game. It's virtually impossible to write an algorithm based on BI that is impervious to timing attacks.

An expert would keep all key and crypto algorithm intermediates in `byte[]` form.

So, you're doing it wrong. Do not roll your own crypto, you'll mess it up. Use existing algorithms.

If you really, really, **really** want to go down this road, you need to learn, *a lot*, before you even start. Begin by analysing a ton of existing implementations. Try to grok every line, try to grok every move. For example, a password hash checking algorithm might contain this code:

```
public boolean isEqual(byte[] a, byte[] b) {
    if (a.length != b.length) throw new IllegalArgumentException("mismatched lengths");
    int len = a.length;
    boolean pass = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (a[i] != b[i]) pass = false;
    }
    return pass;
}
```

and you may simply conclude: Eh. Weird. I guess they copied it from C or something, or they just didn't know they could have removed that method entirely and just replaced it with `java.util.Arrays.equals(a, b);`. Oh well, it doesn't matter.

**and you would be wrong** - that's what I mean by understand it all. Assume no mistakes are made. Arrays.equals can be timing-attacked (the amount of time it takes for it to run tells you something: The earlier the mismatch, the faster it returns. This method takes the same time, but only 'works' if the two inputs are equal in length, so it throws instead of returning the seemingly obvious `false` if that happens).

If you spend that much time analysing them all, you'll have covered this question a few times over.

So, with all that context:

**This answer is a bazooka. You WILL blow your foot off. You do not want to write this code. You do not want to do what you are trying to do. BigInteger is the wrong approach**.

`new BigInteger(8 * 40, secureRandom);` will get the job done properly: Generates a random number between (0 and 2^320-1), inclusive, precisely 40 bytes worth. No more, no less.

40 bytes worth of randomness can be generated as follows:

```
byte[] key = new byte[40];
secureRandom.nextBytes(key);
```

But this is, really, still a grave error unless you really, really, *really* know what you are doing (try finding an existing implementation that has some reliable author or has been reviewed by an expert).

Comment: I only put it into a biginteger to be processed with the cipher. the cipher is US-ASCII bytes which is then converted to a biginteger because java doesnt like normal integers with big boi numbers.

Comment: There are loads of open source crypto impls. For example, [bouncycastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/) is open source and has lots to look at. The cipher is not 'US-ASCII bytes'. "cipher" means 'the algorithm', so that doesn't make sense. If you meant: "The key" - no, it won't be. It'll be raw bytes. If you meant: "The result of encrypting it", no, it won't be. It'll be raw bytes. If you see text, those raw bytes where base64d or whatnot. If the key is entered via a password, an algorithm runs that turns this password into raw bytes to serve as key.

Comment: i understand the cipher isnt "US-ASCII Bytes" i was saying my algorithm uses the us-ascii bytes in the encryption process. sorry if i was un clear. if you want to check out my encryption algorithm you can find it here: https://github.com/N0tA1dan/Krypton